# How to call a javascript function from code-behind of a partially loaded aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net application and I use jquery's .load function to load content into a specific div like so:

```
 $('#pnl').load('/Panel.aspx #panel', loadLogs());
```

From the Panel.aspx page I populate some dropdowns in the code-behind load event, and from there I have some javascript functions(in a separate javascript file) that display text files based on the content of the dropdowns, which is controlled by the change events on the dropdowns. I am having an issue of when the page is loaded, the dropdowns are populated but I need to actually click on one of them to get the files to display. I have tried to call the javascript functions from the load event of Panel.aspx with    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock and they are not firing. I have also tried firing it from  window.onload or $(document).ready from the javascript file and it is still not working.

Any suggestions for how I can get this done?

Comment: "I have also tried firing it from window.onload or $(document).ready from the javascript file and it is still not working." What does not working mean? Are you getting an error? Where's your code?

Comment: $(document).ready does not work because the dropdowns aren't populated yet.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();",true);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately these don't seem to work when I use jQuery's .load function to load the aspx page. I have used them in the past to call javascript functions but unfortunately they are not working at this time, I assume because I am just loading a div from the aspx page, and not the entire page.